# Let $f:G \rightarrow S_{G/H} $ the morphism induced by the action of $G$ by translation. Prove that $f(G)$ is not trivial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

#### Question:

> Let $G$ a finite group and $p$ the smallest prime number that divides $|G|$ . Let $H$ a sub group of indices $p$ of $G$. We write $f:G \rightarrow S_{G/H} $ the morphism induced by the action of $G$ by translation. Prove that $f(G)$ is not trivial.

#### My answer:

1-
By hypotesis we know that the index of $|G/H| = p >1 $ hence $\exists g \in G$ s.t. the equivalent class of $g$ written $[g]$ is different from the equivalent classe of $e_G$ written $[e_G]$.

2-
Now let define the following action translation of the group $G$ on $G$, $L_g(x)=[g] \circ [x]$ with the same $g$ as in "1-". Thus we see that this translation belongs to $f(G)$ by definition and that $L_g(e_G) =[g] \circ [e] = [g] $ that is not equal to the equivalent class of $[e_G]$ so $f(G)$ is not trivial.
Q.E.D.

I have a question concerning my part "2-" that depends directly to my understanding of the question. Indeed when in the question it is written:

> We write $f:G \rightarrow S_{G/H} $ the morphism induced by the action of $G$ by translation.

It means the set of all possible action by translation of $G$ on $G$? Or does it mean something else?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If $G$ has order divisible by a prime $p$ then it is clear that $G$ cannot be trivial.

Comment: Why is there people who want to close the question???? At least express what is wrong.

Comment: Why my answer when I quote chatgpt has been deleted for no valid reason explaining why it is wrong?

Comment: As I said in my comment, your question is completely trivial. How could a group with order divisible by a prime be trivial?

Comment: Your "answer" quoting chatGPT was deleted because text generated by stochastic parrots is not acceptable in this site, period.

Comment: @DerekHolt I ve made an important edit to the question. I have to prove that $f(G)$ is not trivial and not $G$.  There was a mistake in the type sorry.  Now can I know if my answer was correct or not please?

Comment: Regarding your question of what is wrong with that chatGPT answer, chatGPT does not apply deductive logic to obtain valid chains of mathematical reasoning. We require that solution verification questions be first subjected to deductive reasoning, for example by a mathematics student.

Comment: @LeeMosher my question is not about what is wrong on chat gpt . In fact there is nothing from chat gpt in my question. Chat gpt is in one of my answer that has been deleted.

Comment: My comment is addressing the question in your comment of Jan 6 at 20:58.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ be any subgroup.

The set $X$ of (left) cosets of $H$ in $G$ is the set
$$X = \{gH\mid g\in G\}.$$
It has $[G:H]$ elements.

The group $G$ has a **natural** action on $X$ by (left) translation: we define the function $\cdot\colon G\times X\to X$ by
$$a\cdot (gH) = (ag)H.$$
This is well-defined: if $gH=g'H$, then $g^{-1}g'\in H$. Then $(ag)^{-1}(ag')=g^{-1}a^{-1}ag' = g^{-1}g'\in H$, so $(ag)H = (ag')H$.

This is an action: for all $gH\in X$ we have $e\cdot(gH) = (eg)H =gH$. And for all $a,b\in G$, $(ab)\cdot gH = (abg)H = (a(bg))H = a\cdot(bgH) = a\cdot(b\cdot(gH))$.

Like any action, the action of $G$ on $X$ by left translation induces a morphism $G\to S_X$, the group of permutations of $X$. This morphism is **the morphism induced by the action of $G$ on $X$.**

So that sentences refers to a **specific**, **uniquely determined**, action of $G$ on the set of left cosets of $H$. It does **not** mean "all possible actions" of anything, it does **not** mean **any** action of $G$ on itself (it is an action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$, not on $G$). So it definitely means "something else".

Comment: Thk for your answer. I ll read it when i ll have time

Comment: Btw did my answer to this question is correct?

Comment: @OffHakhol I have to wonder how any answer you gave could possibly be considered "correct" if you don't even know what a key term in the argument meant. I did not read what you were writing, because it seemed like it would be a complete waste of time. If you did not understand the question, then your answer cannot possibly be correct, because it would lack understanding.

Comment: Madigin I ve solved the question according to my understanding of it, and I wanted to be sure that this understanding was correct as I had a doubt on it. I do not understand how this assure that my answer is false.

Comment: Hello, I didn't say "It does not mean "all possible actions" of anything, it does not mean any action of $G$ on itself ..." I said that the action that is describe here is all of the morphism of the form "$ A_g: G \times G \rightarrow G ,A_g(x) = g * x$" . So i can choose one of this type in order to prove that $f(G)$ is not trivial. Maybe I haven't been precise enough sorry.

Comment: I ve made an important edit to the question. I have to prove that $f(G)$
 is not trivial and not $G$
. There was a typo mistake, sorry. Now can I know if my answer was correct or not please.